# linker error in Xcode project

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am getting the following linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Message", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in DetailsViewController.o
     (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_Messages)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I remove this?
I checked in my DetailsViewController.m and I don't have any Message class anywhere in there

**UPDATE:**

Before this I had a warning: (this was caused because I added ShareKit into my project)

```
objc[59714]: Class Message is implemented in both /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME and /Users/aditya15417/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/4EFD7570-AD87-48E8-8606-1D5633F65AD9/CTest.app/CTest. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

As suggested by one guy from SO, I need to append the Message class with some other prefix.Therefore I changed the class name of Message to CVMessage everywhere in my class (basically whenever I see Messsage I'd replace it with CVMessage) and then I got this error

Comment: may be a problem of framework importing ,be sure that u added the needed frameworks properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the static analyzer, and see if there are warnings in that file.

You are referencing Messages somewhere in there, even if all you are doing is making use of a call somewhere that's supposed to return a Message class...

You must have a Message class somewhere in your project, check and see if that is being compiled by your target.

Comment: Do a clean build, and re-compile.  If that does not fix it you are still using Message somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the DetailsViewController is in `Compile Sources` of your target.